# A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host error

Tags: c#, sockets, udpclient

I'm developing a program in C# that uses a UDP multicast system. My Multicast group it's using 224.0.0.1 address to communicate.

In all Windows 8 machines it is working fine. However, in a Win 7 64x machine the following error occurs:

> A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host.

Any suggestions what i have to do on the Win7 64x machine, to work?

I have already tried to check route table (on cmd prompt: `route print`).
I saw that only 244.0.0 is being mapped and it works with 244.0.0.0. Thing is I want to use 244.0.0.1, since I only want to use the multicast in a local network.

When I try to make a route add command like this: `route ADD 224.0.0.1 MASK 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.26` (or anything similar) it says:

> The route addition failed: The parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

[Possible MSDN solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4850eb66-b822-411f-8cbe-880f9e9d69d2/cannot-get-service-udpclient-to-receive-data-on-w2008-64bit-but-it-works-fine-on-w2003-32bit)

You will have to translate the VB to C#, that should be trivial.